# What is the use case for Librarian->Additional Dependencies?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

In a static library VC++ project, I've noticed a .lib file from another static library is listed in "Additional Dependencies".

I can't see why you would want to explicitly link one .lib into another, surely the whole point is you add libraries in the project which does all the linking into a DLL/EXE. In my case out of the dozens of libs we use, it's just this one that's added in this way. What is the reason for this functionality and when is it needed?

Comment: Most likely to make sure that the code for the dependency is recompiled (if necessary) when building the dependent project. Would be especially important if "Link-Time Code Generation" is enabled.

Comment: The ability to merge multiple libraries into a single .lib file is a core capability of the [library manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/managing-a-library?view=msvc-160).  And supported by VS.  Not terribly common, but useful so the library consumer has to memorize only a single filename to get their executable linked.